Linearizing around a point in system of nonlinear differential equations
Consider nonlinear system for $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$:
$$X'(t) = X(t) + Y(t) - 2$$
$$Y'(t) = 3 - X(t) Y(t)$$
subject to initial condition $X(t) = Y(t) = 0$. Computer package (like Mathematica) gives the numerical solution:  with $X(t)$ in red and $Y(t)$ in blue.
I wanna linearize around specific point $T \ne 0$, where $X(T)=0$ and $Y(T) \ne 0$.
Numerics says the point is $T \approx 1.25$, where $X(T) = 0$ and $Y(T) \approx 5.87$.
How to find, approximately or exactly, this point $T$ and $Y(T)$ without using numerical solution to the ODEs?

Did you try a series solution ? Mathematica function is  AsymptoticDSolveValue[....]

Hint
Since the important function is $X(t)$, first of all eliminate $Y(t)$ from the first equation and plug it in the second.
$$X''+(X-1)X'-X^2+2X-3=0$$ the conditions being $X(0)=0$ and $X'(0)=-2$.
As said in comments, use a series solution to fourth order in order to be able to solve explicitly the cubic for $t$.
Numerically, $X(t)=0$ for $t=1.26622$.
